# children process waits for another one to complete and main() doesn't execute to the end

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

While `fork()`ing 4 children processes, I get into a `wait()` after the first  children process' execution and the next one doesn't even get executed. I am not sure why this phenomenon occurs. I am not an expert in forking and every tip is appreciated.

```
Input data: ./forkexample 2 3 4 5
```

And here is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{

    if (argc != 5)
    {
        printf("Argument # is invalid. %s < 4\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    float a = atof(argv[1]);

    float b = atof(argv[2]);

    float c = atof(argv[3]);

    float d = atof(argv[4]);

    if ((a == 0.0) || (b == 0.0) || (c == 0.0) || (d == 0.0))
    {
        printf("Conversion error, invalid parameters!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int ossz[2], kiv[2], szor[2], oszt[2];
    int mainpid;
    if ((pipe(ossz) < 0))
        perror("pipe error(/)");
    if ((pipe(kiv) < 0))
        perror("pipe error(*)");
    if ((pipe(szor) < 0))
        perror("pipe error(-)");
    if ((pipe(oszt) < 0))
        perror("pipe error(*)");

    mainpid = getpid();

    pid_t osszeg, kivonas, szorzat, hanyados;

    //            (a+b*c) / (a-b+d-c) + a*b*c*d;

    //       *****************************+***********************************

    if ((osszeg = fork()) == 0)
    {
        if (mainpid != getpid())
        { //osszeadast vegez el
            float b1, c1, byteb1, bytec1;
            byteb1 = read(ossz[0], &b1, sizeof(float));
            printf("%d  Osszeg read in %.2f\n", getpid(), b1);

            bytec1 = read(ossz[0], &c1, sizeof(float));
            printf("%d Osszeg read in %.2f\n", getpid(), c1);
            close(ossz[0]);
            c1 += b1;

            write(ossz[1], &c1, sizeof(float));
            printf("%d Osszeadas wrote %.2f\n", getpid(), c1);
        }
        else if (getpid() < 0)
        {
            printf("Error creating children process, cprog stops!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    //       *****************************-***********************************

    if ((kivonas = fork()) == 0)
    {
        if (mainpid != getpid())
        { //kivonast vegez el
            float b2, c2, byteb2, bytec2;
            byteb2 = read(kiv[0], &b2, sizeof(float));
            printf("%d Kivonas read in %.2f\n", getpid(), b2);

            bytec2 = read(kiv[0], &c2, sizeof(float));
            printf("%d Kivonas read in %.2f\n", getpid(), c2);
            close(kiv[0]);
            c2 -= b2;

            write(kiv[1], &c2, sizeof(float));
            printf("%d Kivonas wrote %.2f\n", getpid(), c2);
        }
        else if (getpid() < 0)
        {
            printf("Error creating children process, cprog stops!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    //       ***************************** Multiplication***********************************

    if ((szorzat = fork()) == 0)
    {
        if (mainpid != getpid())
        { //szorzast vegez el
            float b3, c3, byteb3, bytec3;
            byteb3 = read(szor[0], &b3, sizeof(float));
            printf("%d Szorzat read in %.2f\n", getpid(), b3);

            bytec3 = read(szor[0], &c3, sizeof(float));
            printf("%d Szorzat read in %.2f\n", getpid(), c3);
            close(szor[0]);
            c3 *= b3;

            write(szor[1], &c3, sizeof(float));
            printf("%d Szorzat wrote %.2f\n", getpid(), c3);
        }
        else if (getpid() < 0)
        {
            printf("Error creating children process, cprog stops!\n");
        }
    }

    //       *****************************Division***********************************

    if ((hanyados = fork()) == 0)
    {
        if (mainpid != getpid())
        { //osztast vegez el
            float b4, c4, byteb4, bytec4;
            byteb4 = read(oszt[0], &b4, sizeof(float));
            printf("%d Oszto read in %.2f\n", getpid(), b4);

            bytec4 = read(oszt[0], &c4, sizeof(float));
            printf("%d Oszto read in %.2f\n", getpid(), c4);
            close(oszt[0]);
            c4 = c4 / b4;

            write(oszt[1], &c4, sizeof(float));
            printf("%d Oszto wrote %.2f\n", getpid(), c4);
        }
        else if (getpid() < 0)
        {
            printf("Error creating children process, cprog stops!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    float szorzaser, osztaser, kivonaser, osszeger, vegeredmeny;
    write(szor[1], &b, sizeof(float));
    write(szor[1], &c, sizeof(float));
    wait(NULL);
    read(szor[0], &szorzaser, sizeof(float)); //b*c
    printf("%d Parent got: %.2f /n", getpid(), szorzaser);

    write(ossz[1], &a, sizeof(float));
    write(ossz[1], &szorzaser, sizeof(float));
    wait(NULL);
    read(ossz[0], &osszeger, sizeof(float)); //a+szorzaser(b*c)
    printf("%d Parent got: %.2f /n", getpid(), osszeger);

    //***********************a+b*c**********************************************

    write(ossz[1], &b, sizeof(float));
    write(ossz[1], &d, sizeof(float));
    wait(NULL);

    read(ossz[0], &osszeger, sizeof(float)); //b+d
    printf("%d Parent got: %.2f /n", getpid(), osszeger);
    write(kiv[1], &a, sizeof(float));
    write(kiv[1], &osszeger, sizeof(float));
    wait(NULL);

    read(kiv[0], &kivonaser, sizeof(float)); //a-osszeger(b+d)
    printf("%d Paren  t got: %.2f /n", getpid(), kivonaser);
    write(kiv[1], &kivonaser, sizeof(float));
    write(kiv[1], &c, sizeof(float));
    wait(NULL);

    read(kiv[0], &kivonaser, sizeof(float)); //kivonaser(a-b+d-c)
    printf("%d Parent got: %.2f /n", getpid(), kivonaser);
    write(oszt[1], &kivonaser, sizeof(float));
    write(oszt[1], &osszeger, sizeof(float)); //betesszuk az osztas pipejaba
    wait(NULL);

    read(oszt[0], &osztaser, sizeof(float)); //(a+b*c) / (a-b+d-c)
    printf("%d Parent got: %.2f /n", getpid(), osztaser);

    //*************************(a-b+d-c)*********************************************

    write(szor[1], &a, sizeof(float));
    write(szor[1], &b, sizeof(float));
    wait(NULL);
    read(szor[0], &szorzaser, sizeof(float)); //a*b
    printf("%d Parent got: %.2f /n", getpid(), szorzaser);

    write(szor[1], &szorzaser, sizeof(float));
    write(szor[1], &c, sizeof(float));
    wait(NULL);
    read(szor[0], &szorzaser, sizeof(float)); //a*b*c
    printf("%d Parent got: %.2f /n", getpid(), szorzaser);

    write(szor[1], &szorzaser, sizeof(float));
    write(szor[1], &c, sizeof(float));
    wait(NULL);
    read(szor[0], &szorzaser, sizeof(float)); //a*b*c*d
    printf("%d Parent got: %.2f /n", getpid(), szorzaser);
    //************************* a*b*c*d *********************************************
    write(ossz[1], &osztaser, sizeof(float));
    write(ossz[1], &szorzaser, sizeof(float));
    wait(NULL);
    read(ossz[0], &vegeredmeny, sizeof(float)); //(a+b*c) / (a-b+d-c)+ a*b*c*d;
    printf("%d Parent got: %.2f /n", getpid(), vegeredmeny);

    close(ossz[0]);
    close(ossz[1]);
    close(kiv[0]);
    close(kiv[1]);
    close(szor[0]);
    close(szor[1]);
    close(oszt[0]);
    close(oszt[1]);

    printf("%d got the final result: %.2f!\n", getpid(), vegeredmeny);
    return (0);
}
```

The whole process tries to calculate `(a+b*c)/(a-b+d-c)+a*b*c*d` using the children processes. After compliation and running this sequence runs:

```
vargaelod23@vargaelod23-M5400:~/LinuxI/fork$ ./fork1 2 3 4 5

5459 Szorzat read in 3.00

5459 Szorzat read in 4.00

5459 Szorzat wrote 12.00
```

After this, the calculation waits for something and I can't figure out why.

Comment: What are those getpid() calls for? fork() returns a pid of the creted process in the parent process. And the getpid() < 0 checks (instead of checking fork() result) make no sense at all.

Comment: Well thats just for making sure we are in the children process. My supervisor asked me too but told me it is correct as is it but it's useless. @JacekKonieczny

Comment: `getpid` is one of the very few system calls that can never fail, so checking whether it returned a negative value is indeed useless.

Comment: Its just that checking if thefork is created succesfully is made in the previous for. I know I could've left that if out easily but, to be honest, was lazy to correct before finding out the source of the main error. I'll correct it tho before finalizing the code.

Comment: @VargaElőd The correct way to check whether `fork` succeeded is to see if it returned -1.  For instance `if ((osszeg = fork()) == 0) { ... } /*parent */ if (osszeg == -1) { perror("fork"); exit(1); }`

Answer (score 1):

Your child processes do not exit, but continue running the code intended for the parent process. So after the first child writes its result to the pipe, it starts forking another subprocesses and then writes again to its own pipe and enters `wait()`. Then you have a deadlock – the parent process waits for the first child to exit and the first child waits for its child to exit.

You also don't check for error condition on any of the `write()` calls. If you did, you would see that unexpected `write()` call is being made.

Adding `_exit()` calls to the child paths should help, but there are many other things wrong in this code.

Comment: I tested with adding exit(0) at the end of every single child process, but it still goes into deadlock. That was the first version of the code, but that way it still gets stuck right there.